# Open public oracle apex page from other web app

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-18.2

Is it possible to open oracle apex page (with static content) without left menu and navigation bar from other web application.

Example: I want to modify the content of the page over oracle apex but on other web app I need to load this page in iframe or open in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to see the application and modify it from another "web app" and basically you want to remove the navigation menu and navigation bar from the pages of your app?

If so, you can simple remove navigation menu and navigation bar for all pages of your application:

Follow these steps:

1. Go to app builder and select your application;
2. Click "Shared components";
3. Under user interface section, select "User Interface Attributes";
4. At the section "User Interfaces", click on the pencil to edit your interface;
5. Scroll down to "Navigation Menu", in "Display Navigation" check the option "No";
6. Scroll down to "Navigation Bar", in "Navigation Bar List", select the first option "Select Navigation List", that will make that no list will be presented.

---

To remove from specific pages:

1. Open your page that you want to edit on page designer;
2. The first entry from the left side panel you have the page properties, click on it:
   [image]
3. Then from the panel that opened, in "**Appearance**" section, change the attribute "**Page template**" to "**Minimal (No navigation)**", that will remove the navigation menu from this page;
4. To remove the navigation bar you will have to add some CSS in the page, to do this, scroll down from the place you ended up at step 3 until section "**CSS**", put the following code in the attribute "**Inline**":

> ```
> .apex-side-nav .t-Body-actions, .apex-side-nav .t-Body-nav, .apex-side-nav .t-Body-title {
>     top: 0px !important; 
>   }
>
> .t-Header-branding {
>     height: 0px; 
>   }
> ```

5. Do these steps to all pages that you want to have the Navigation menu and bar removed.

Comment: Tnx for answer, Is it possible only for one page in aplication  hide menu and navigation bar.

Comment: Yes it is. I've added it on my answer.